# aligning two paragraphs next to each other, in the center

Tags: html, css

This may be another beginner question, but I just can't get 2 paragraphs to align themselves next to each other, in the center of the page. I can align them next to each other to the left or to the right, but they don't align next to each other in the center of the page.

here is my html(sorry for not responding as quickly as I should've):

```
    <p> bla bla bl balbal blabsljfblasj bfljasbfladsb fasdbf ab falsdbf als fbasljfbasljf basljfb alsj fbaslj fbaslj bfaslj fbalsj fbalsj fblajs fbasljbf aljbflajsb</p>

                    <p> bla bla bl balbal blabsljfblasj bfljasbfladsb fasdbf ab falsdbf als fbasljfbasljf basljfb alsj fbaslj fbaslj bfaslj fbalsj fbalsj fblajs fbasljbf aljbflajsb</p>
```

here is my CSS for the paragraphs:

```
     p { 
 color: black;
 width: 300px;
 height:200px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: BenchNine , cursive; }
```

Thanks to anyone who answers, any help is appreciated!

Comment: share your html code too.

Comment: Could you upload the HTML as well?

Comment: You can't have 2 `<p>` to be aligned next to each other unless you're using a table or a bootstrap div method.

Comment: *"here is my html"* - is that "it"? Well, Mihai's answer seems to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41244828/1415724 and so have I up there.

Comment: yeah that's it for the paragraphs. I'm just a beginner and I'm still learning. Thank you to everyone who responded!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a number of ways to do this.

1. see solution below with **`display:flex`**

*if you want to align them side-by-side centered and also centered vertically, just add `justify-content:center` to the `.wrap` div*

```css
   p { 
 color: black;
 width: 300px;
 height:200px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: BenchNine , cursive; }
 
 .wrap { display:flex;align-items:center}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">


<p>
This is a paragraph
</p>
<p>
This is another paragraph
</p>
</div>
```

2. solution with **`display:table;`** and **`display:table-cell`**

```css
   p { 
 color: black;
 width: 300px;
 height:200px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: BenchNine , cursive; }
 
 .wrap { display:table;width:100%}
 p { display:table-cell}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">


<p>
This is a paragraph
</p>
<p>
This is another paragraph
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To align two different `para` in `center` of page, so for that `wrap` them in a `div` and set it `margin` to `auto`, as below. To align `both para` in same line i.e. `horizontal` use `display:inline-block or float:left`.

```css
div{
  width:420px;
  height:80px;
  margin:auto;
}
p { 
 color: black;
 font-family: BenchNine , cursive; 
 margin:0px auto;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 width:200px;
 height:60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Hi demo Text 1</p>
<p>Hi demo Text 2</p>
</div>
```